# HowTo import JSNLog module using TypeScript, SystemJS, JSPM

Tags: typescript, systemjs, jspm, jsnlog

I fail to import the JL module from JSNLog in my TypeScript project.
I installed my dependencies using JSPM:

```
jspm install npm:jsnlog
```

The documentation gives an example for node:

```
var JL = require('jsnlog').JL;
```

I tried to make it available in my project (for the browser) but I cannot make it work:

```
import JL from 'jsnlog' // TypeError: jsnlog_1.default.createConsoleAppender is not a function
import {JL} from 'jsnlog' // TypeError: Cannot read property 'createConsoleAppender' of undefined
const JL = require('jsnlog').JL // Error: require is not defined
import JL = require('jsnlog').JL // TypeError: JL.createConsoleAppender is not a function
```

Any wizard out there who can point me into the right direction?

```
// tsconfig.json

"compilerOptions": {
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true, 
    "experimentalDecorators": true, 
    "removeComments": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node", 
    "target": "es5"
  }
```

Comment: `import JL = require('jsnlog').JL` should work. The error you see seems to be related to the library itself.

Comment: For one reason or another that transpiles to `var JL = require('jsnlog'); JL;`

Answer (score 0):

According to the JNSLog [author](https://github.com/mperdeck/jsnlog.js/issues/19):

> jsnlog.js is actually written in TypeScript:
>
> https://github.com/mperdeck/jsnlog.js/blob/master/jsnlog.ts
>   I used the TypeScript compiler to compile jsnlog.ts to jsnlog.js (which is pure > JavaScript).

Since your project is already typescript based I would import using the jsnlog.d.ts file (you might need to create this yourself).